# Qual o escopo das variáveis em uma página com ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, escopo-de-variáveis, partialview

Tenho uma *view layout*:

```
<div>
    <h1>Pagina Principal<h1>
</div>
<div>
    <h3>Simular<h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Partials/Teste/Simular", new SimularViewModel(cpf: Model.Cliente.Cpf, idCampanha: Model.Ocorrencia.IdCampanha));}
</div>
<div>
    <h3>opções<h3>
</div>
<div class="row">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Partials/Cadastro/_Opcoes", new CadastroViewModel(cpf: Model.Cliente.Cpf, idCampanha: Model.Ocorrencia.IdCampanha));}
</div>
```

Que contem 2 *partials views*:

#### Simular

```
<div>
    <label>texto</label>
    <label>texto</label>
</div>
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Ir para Simulação", "Index", "Simular",
          new { cpf = Model.Cpf, origem = ViewBag.Origem},
          new { @class = "btn btn-brand float-right btn btn-brand float-right" })
</div>
```

#### Cadastrar

```
<div>
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, Model.StatusOcorrencias.Select(so => new SelectListItem() { Text = so.Status, Value = so.Id.ToString() }), "Selecione", new
     {
         @class = "form-control m-input m-input--square",
         @id = "dllStatus",
         style = "width: 100%"
      })
</div>
<div>
     @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Observacao, new { @class = "form-control m-input", maxlength = "500" })
</div>
```

Desenhei mais ou menos como fica o *layout*:

[image: Layout paint]

Eu preciso passar as informações dos campos que podem ser preenchidos pelo usuário na *partial view* 2 `Cadastrar`, para o botão `ActionLink` da *partial view* 1 `Simular`.

Como fazer isso?

Como funciona o escopo da variável nesse caso?

E se tem como eu retornar o valor da *partial* para a *view* principal e da *view* principal para a *partial*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua *partial view* você precisa criar um *model* para receber o objeto que está passando na *view* principal, algo assim:

```
@model SimularViewModel
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ASP.NET/Model.cs).

Aí sim você terá um modelo disponível nesta visão nova.

O escopo é igual a um código normal, cada *view* é como se fosse uma função.

Nunca tentei devolver um valor para a visão principal, mas isso me parece errado, provavelmente essa visão parcial está fazendo mais que apenas apresentar dados que é a função dela.